# How to add 'Properties > Camera > Focal Length' to 3D View Panel?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, camera

I would like to add the prop from Properties > Camera > Focal Length to a panel in the 3D View, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel) :
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "My Panel"

    def draw(self, context) :
        TheLayout = self.layout
        TheLayout.prop(context.space_data, "lens")  #Like this, but for the Camera's focal length.
```

The console suggests:

```
bpy.context.object.data.lens
```

And this gives me the value of the function:

```
bpy.data.cameras[bpy.context.active_object.name].lens
```

But how do I make a widget with this function in a 3D View panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting with the templates available. You need to import the blender python module & register your panel.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel


class MyPanel(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'  # properties section 'n'
#    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'  # tool bar section 't'
#    bl_category = "My Tab"  # add to specific tab
    bl_label = "My Panel"

    def draw(self, context):
        TheLayout = self.layout
        col = TheLayout.column(align=True)
        col.label(text="viewport lens")
        col.prop(context.space_data, "lens")
        col.separator()
        col.prop(context.scene, "camera")
        col.separator()
        col.prop(context.scene.camera.data, "lens")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Edited

- Removed Loop of all objects to find multiple cameras.
- Added scene camera prop for local selection in the event of multiple
  cameras

.

Comment: `for obj in context.scene.objects` may get slow in a big scene. Probably `context.scene.camera` is enough to draw the property.

Comment: Thank you @Ratt & dr. Sybren. I wonder how you got to (bpy.context.scene.camera.data, "lens") would work? Which it does! Googling it, this came up(for further reading): https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/info_quickstart.html